# Sending "search" query with Angular 2 (angularfire2)

Tags: angular, search, angularfire2

I'm working with Angular 2 and the angularfire2 framework.

I try to send a search-query to the firebase realtime database, and have tried a lot of codes, also with ...startAt("") ... endAt(""). Can someone give me an example please?

My JSON data structur:

[image]

Accordant the search string, a sub-collection of my list should be received as response. The search should be runnable at the fields **tmp_name** and **short_desc**.

Thanks a lot.

Cengiz

Comment: Have forget to add: It's similar to the WHERE Clause in SQL: "SELECT * FROM templates WHERE INSTR(tmp_name, 'WordPress')

Comment: you may want to look at this question. It  addresses what you are asking https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47841119/creating-an-auto-complete-serach-using-angularfire2-and-firestore