# match the query with the first letter of name

Tags: nativescript-angular

I have a search UI that is already working using Nativescript Angular but it only returns searched name after only typing that specific name in the search bar. So, I am trying to figure out how to return for example all the names that start with a letter (A). If I typed letter (A) in the searchbar.

I already tried to use `\uf8ff` but it returns all the names stored in the database when I just type any letter so I removed it.

```
const query: firestore.Query = firebase.firestore().collection("user")
    .where("nameToSearch", ">=",searchValue)
    .where("nameToSearch", "<=",searchValue)
}
```

> -no expected

It shows the searched name only after fully typing the name not just by typing first letter.

Comment: Try something [**like this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48369272/3937794)

Comment: Duplicated, try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46574143/8330509

Comment: #sourav.. still when i press any key in the searchbar it returns all the names stored in the Datsbase